# Broken Connection in Spring Data JPA and Hikari Connection Pooling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

In one of spring boot microservice app, i was having problem with connection leakage. Some of the connection were not being returned to the Pool and i was using only default configuration for Hikari. Now I put a leakDetectionThreshold and it starts explicitly taking back connections and returning it to the Pool. My question is related to these broken connections, even though as per the specification of Hikari pool, if a connection retuned to pool in a broken state, Pool handlers would rollback the transactions so thay It didn't bleed out for the next consumer. But in my case, transactions were not rolled back. What is happening here?